# i want to insert data in MARKS table and STUDENT table i have time/date column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have two tables :

1. STUDENT(s_id, s_Name, last date of update marks)
2. MARKS(id, s_name, eng_marks,maths_marks, s_id)

I want to update table STUDENT with current date and time (table last date of marks) when I insert data in MARKS table.

Comment: PLEASE DO NOT SHOUT AT ME

Comment: Could you please properly format the question and remove the uppercase shouting from the title, that would get you a better chance of answers.

Comment: To insert and update data, the SQL commands you're looking for are (unsurprisingly) "INSERT" and "UPDATE".

Comment: i HAVE 2 tables STUDENT(s_id, s_Name, last date of update marks) and MARKS( id, s_name, eng_marks,maths_marks, s_id) , .i want when i insert data  in MARKS table , in STUDENT  (table last date of marks) update   with current date and time

Comment: @KaranGoomer Please edit the question, don't put it as a comment.

Comment: could u tell me the solution???

Answer (score 0):

There are two options here, one which is neater than the other. Here they are, with the less least one first:

1. Use a TRIGGER AFTER INSERT on the marks table to update the related record in the student table. TRIGGERS are resource-heavy tools, and if there's an obvious workaround, that would be preferable.
2. Make two INSERT statements on the database when you want to insert marks. First, insert the marks, and then update the student table with the appropriate date.

Personally, I would choose the latter approach as it is a simple way to avoid a trigger.

Good luck, and let us know how it goes.